# How to leave addons activated in safe mode in firefox?

Tags: firefox, safe-mode

I'm wondering where is the file which manages extensions de/activation in safe mode? It seems that the XPIProvider.jsm file from omni.ja archive describe in other post doesn't exist anymore.

I'm running firefox 53.0.2 (32 bits)

Thanks Julien

Comment: anyone to help me?

Comment: anyone to help me?

Comment: Anyone to help me?